# Python TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, dictionary

I copied this code from a book:

```
lyst = {'Hi':'Hello'}
def changeWord(sentence):
    def getWord(word):
        lyst.get(word, word)
    return ''.join(map(getWord, sentence.split()))
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    cambiaPronome('ciao')
  File "C:\Python33\2.py", line 6, in cambiaPronome
    return ''.join(map(getWord, list(frase)))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `return ''.join(map(getWord, list(frase)))` is not from the book. Why don't you show us the actual code you wrote?

Comment: You are not returning anything from the `getWord` method.

Comment: For anyone who's interested, this bug does occur on pg. 236 of *Fundamentals of Python: First Programs* by Kenneth Lambert, and so wasn't originated by the OP.

Comment: @DSM, how did you find that?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: googled the line of code least likely to have been written by a beginner (the `return` line.)

Comment: I'm italian and i've the italian version... After pasted the code, i have decided to translate the code, but i have not traslate the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getWord` function doesn't explicitly return anything, so it implicitly returns `None`. Try returning something, e.g.:

```
def getWord(word):
    return lyst.get(word, word)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to write to a string a type which is NoneType. That's not allowed.

If you're interested in getting the `None` values as well one of the things  you can do is convert them to strings.

And you can do it with a list comprehension, like:

`return ''.join([str(x) for x in map(getWord, sentence.split())])`

But to do it properly in this case, you have to return something on the inner function, else you have the equivalent to `return None`