# How to find the matched info for all the elements in the list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I want to find the matched info for all the elements in the list. For example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1','2'],'Fruit':['apple|banana','banana|watermelon']})
        Fruit             ID
0   apple|banana           1
1   banana|watermelon      2
```

I also have a data set with the price of fruit:

```
price=pd.DataFrame({'Fruit':['apple','banana','watermelon','pear'],
                    'price':['1.49','0.59','5.99','1.99']})
    Fruit       price
0   apple       1.49
1   banana      0.59
2   watermelon  5.99
3   pear        1.99
```

I want to find all the matched price on the fruit list:

```
         Fruit          ID  price
0   apple|banana        1   1.49|0.59
1   banana|watermelon   2   0.59|5.99
```

I know I can use left join to find the matched info for one single element. I'm not sure how to find all the matched info.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did the below answer help? If so, feel free to accept, or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way using a list comprehension:

```
s = price.set_index('Fruit')['price']

df['price'] = ['|'.join(list(map(s.get, i))) for i in df['Fruit'].str.split('|')]

print(df)

               Fruit ID      price
0       apple|banana  1  1.49|0.59
1  banana|watermelon  2  0.59|5.99
```

Comment: One more question, it did worked on this example data. However, when I applied on my big data, it got an error "TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, NoneType found". Do you know the possible reason? Thank you!

Comment: You are correct. I find the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222697/python-typeerror-sequence-item-0-expected-str-instance-nonetype-found